How to check if address is contained public name?
How to check if address is contained public name or owned by AMM? so when you address is checked on solscan.io/account/address is contained public name or not? if yes it return the public name like in the image below, it show Raydium as the public name.


could you provide more context on your question.

@Jimii check again sir

These are internal to Solscan.  If a program has it's IDL published, you can use that to fetch the name otherwise nothing you can use
